# Rails how to access a hash in model from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4.  I have a hash in a model and I'd like to be able to access it via the rails console for testing some code.  How do I do this?

```
foo = {'one' => 'ONE', 'two' => 'TWO'}
```

I've tried the following, but it gives me an "undefined method 'foo' in class..."

```
ModelName.foo['one']
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use foo as a constant? If so, you can set it and then reference it as:

```
class ModelName
  FOO = {'one' => 'ONE', 'two' => 'TWO'}
end

ModelName::FOO['one']
```

An alternative to keep the reference as you have it:

```
class ModelName
  def self.foo
    {'one' => 'ONE', 'two' => 'TWO'}
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I had just found this same thing in another app I worked on while ago, and in it I used a constant for the hash.  So easy to forget the simple things.  Cheers!